# How to get difference in seconds between created_at and updated_at

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am creating a Rail 3.2 web app. In this app I got timetracking model.
First the user creates a timetracking record (created_at) and then stops the same timetracking record (updated_at). How can I get the difference in seconds between these two dates? Perhaps best to have it in epoc?

I will use the result together with distance_of_time_in_words.

Thankful for all help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried subtracting them?

```
>> a = Time.now
=> 2013-06-12 13:09:08 +0200
>> b = Time.now
=> 2013-06-12 13:09:11 +0200
>> b - a
=> 3.791783
```

Or did you mean doing this in SQL? (If so, look into your RDBMS' date and time functions/operators.)